# How to access the method of the java project which is running on JBoss server?

Tags: java, methods, jboss

I have the java project along with its some JAR, WAR file. I have deployed the WAR file on server. As I deployed it, I am able to access the link

```
http://localhost:8080/prj-name/
```

in the browser and also able to access the project.

Along with this project I got the one link as:
`http://localhost:8080/prj-name/rest/application.wadl` with this project and I have to refer this file while accessing the methods. What I did is I converted wadl file to Java Stub using wadl2java tool. The Java stub is nothing but the interface.

But as I am trying to access the method from URL I am getting error in the browser as HTTP 401 Unauthorized. I entered the method in the link as:

```
http://localhost:8080/prj-name/?method=method-name&param=value
```

So my question is that If I want to call the method from the project which is running in JBoss server then how should I access the method? Is it right approach to refer Java Stub instead of wadl file?

Please advice

Comment: "HTTP 401", it says that your request must be authenticated to access the method.Can you post the Java code with which you access the method? What API have you used to develop this REST based services? Consider tagging you questions properly.

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM : The link I have posted above to access the method, I just used that link to access the method. I have write the code to read the link like this:
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/prj-name/?method=method-name&param=value); and try to read using BufferedReader

Comment: How to remove the error HTTP 401 error?